# Adding jar file in libs vs. adding dependencies in gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

We are using `projectlombok` in our android app. Our approach to use this library is -
We have added `lombok.jar` to the android studio - inside `libs` folder and using `compile files('libs/lombok.jar')`

However, on the [project home page](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle) of projectlombok the approach explained to add it is like below,

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'
}
```

Is there any performance or app-size impact of one approach over the other?

Answer (score 0):

One of the biggest differences is the amount of work required to upgrade to a new version of the library. If you use Gradle, then all it takes is a small edit to your build.gradle file. The other option requires downloading the JAR file manually and copying it to the libs directory.

For JAR-only libraries, this difference is pretty small. However, for libraries which also include Android resources, a JAR file is insufficient. You have to build a AAR file instead and bring it into your build process. Gradle manages all of this for you.

Comment: yes, that is definitely 1 diff.  wanted to check if overall app size will be impacted though.. i am doing that test and will post the update in my Question